# Errors when installing PyGame in Python

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I am trying to make a Virtual Assistant and for that i am using PyGame but when i am trying to install PyGame am stuck with this errors, is there any way to get around? I have tried everything but did not succeed

Errors -

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio: started
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-u4fzx0xa --python-tag cp38
       cwd: /private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/
  Complete output (18 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
  #include "portaudio.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pip-record-xbb40_p1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4b/qbpxp4qj1cd8h1m1x1vd59xw0000gn/T/pip-record-xbb40_p1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me to resolve this errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're missing a dependency called portAudio. Try the following:

```
brew install portaudio
```

[Brew installation guide in case you don't have it already](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: This helped me to install PyGame but when i run my code now i get this error - (check above in my question)

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question for your runtime error

Comment: Did it here please help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617905/runtime-errors-with-gtts-this-happens-with-me-in-most-projects